# offline application client-server

Tags: c#, client-server, offline, offlineapps

i want develop a desktop application for a **customer** (factory) that store **personal information of personnel**. in this application we define level for application users. i mean one user is top level (parent) that can see all personnel data stored and second level (first child) can see its data and its childs data and etc . exact like tree view and each node can see its data and child data. that means parent factory has some childs factory and childs have childs.

in online application you can handle this so easy but this one is offline . now they enter their personnel information in their application  (each user has different PC).

**now you know the big problem is merging childs DBs to their parent DB**.Ch3 And Ch4 Send Their DBs to Ch1 And same for Ch5,Ch2 Then Ch1 And Ch2 to Parent.we have conflict in merging for example one person from ch1 went to ch3 the data duplicate or if when parent have all data one child change one person national code (unique key) then in merging we cannot update existing then conflict in merging and lots of problem you know .

**Any Idea for Merging DB s!?**

[image]

---

abit about my Data Base . personnelInformation is main table that has a related table with name PersonnelFactory that each row has one person factory and enter date and exit date and personnel code. a table for person rank (job) in that factory . this is small part of DB for you understand problems.

Comment: Sound like the only problem is that you don't have a merging strategy? How do you want to handle duplicates? I'd use GUIDs as keys to avoid dupes on keys.

Comment: seems you said true but in big db with a lot related table duplicate , Updated and Deleted rows are problem and relation make things complex . the question is : is there any way DLL , program etc to help me or i must do it my self with C# code. and i read syncframework seems it cant help me.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a central database at Server side. On the client side, clients will make changes locally and whenever internet is available they can upload their changes and download changes made by other through that central Server database.

Take a look at Microsoft Sync Framework. It automatically deals with many complex merging scenarios. There are many solution to avoid duplicate keys on client, one of them is to use `GUID` or `uniqueidentifies`.

Here are some useful resource

[Introduction to Sync Framework Database Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx)

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx)

Comment: i think sync is for 1 server and 1 client not many client in tree view like server-Client.i read those link it cant handle many client.

Comment: @MamadR No, it supports all kind of scenarios including One Server many clients.

Comment: hmm can u show me a link or tutorial that can show me how can i do that for many clients(offline) and help for treeview like server-client strategy.and you know in big db with related table its complex can sync handle it?